# If I put my gamer ID into a preowned new 3ds Xl that has games already downloaded, will the games be affected in any way?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I'm planning on getting a preowned New 3ds Xl from someone and the listing says it has games downloaded onto the system. I have my own 3DS (the older version) and I created a gamer ID on it to help get in touch with my friends in order to play on a game together even when we're far away.
I'm worried the games would be affected somehow if I were to input my gamer ID into the system. I'm just a dummy who has no idea how this stuff works so I would appreciate it if someone were to help me with my issue. I haven't found any other person asking this so I decided to reach out for myself. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You won't be able to launch the games if you change the Nintendo Network linked to the console.